# how to fetch data in apollo cilent

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a problem fetching data with apollo client in reactJS, I can fetch this area  but I can't reach the item and  receive an error

console output  : `{getProducts: Array(3)}`

Code For accessing items:

```
data.getProducts.map(iteam => console.log(iteam));
```

Error received :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProducts')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Check Data Load Complete before Access data

```
 if (!loading && !error) {//Access Here}
```